# Text shadow using CSS

Tags: html, css

[image: Text Effect]

Hey, I am trying to achieve the text styling using box shadow but couldn't get even close. Can you guid me on which approach I should use. Here is what I tried so far:

```css
.head {
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #766d36, 0 2px 0 #766d36, 0px 0px 50px #928848, 0 0px 0px #928848, 0 -1px 0 #574f1b, 0 0px 10px rgba(232, 217, 119, 0.1), 0 0 12px rgba(232, 217, 119, 0.1), 0 -3px 15px rgba(232, 217, 119, 0.3), 0 0px 73px rgba(232, 217, 119, 1), 0 4px 29px rgba(232, 217, 119, 0.25), 0 3px 1px rgba(232, 217, 119, 1), 0 15px 20px rgba(232, 217, 119, 0.15);
  color: #aea254;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="head">Enter</h1>
```

Comment: click the text effect link to see what I am trying to achieve

Comment: can you not use a tool like this? https://css3gen.com/text-shadow/

Comment: Why do you want to use box-shadow instead of text-shadow? Your image shows a text-shadow.

Answer (score 3):

Found this one, hope this helps:
https://codepen.io/adambundy/pen/HtmaK

```
h1 {
  font: bold 200px arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #565656;
  color: transparent;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gjVrdx

```
.bg {
background-color: #e8d977;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
}

.title {
  padding: 10px 22px;
  font-size: 55px;
  font-family:  sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 10px 6px 7px rgba(255,255,255,0.5) !important;
  opacity: 0.2;
}

<div class='bg'>
  <h1 class='title'>Enter</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: You should never use `!important`, it results in more problems then it _“solves”_.

Comment: I know, just add it in codepen.io, because style was not showing, otherwise we should try to not use !important.